# My right border of my image disappears when link is clicked - CSS, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The implementation can be [seen here](http://fiwishop.com/feedback/feedback.html).

When you click the '3 squares' button, look at the rightmost border of the rightmost image - it disappears. The same thing happens when you click the '4 squares'.

However, when you go back to default view - i.e. the 2 squares - the border comes back. What could be causing this and how do I fix it?

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<div id="compare_view">

    <div id="viewbar" class="compv-navbar">
        <a href=""><img src="images/2-up-icon-grey.png" alt="2-up-view" data-id="2"></a> | 
        <a href=""><img src="images/3-up-icon-grey.png" alt="3-up-view" data-id="3"></a> | 
        <a href=""><img src="images/4-up-icon-grey.png" alt="4-up-view" data-id="4"></a> | 
        <span id="viewname" class="view_name">2-up</span>
    </div>  

<div id="slider-code">
    <a class="buttons prev" href="#"></a>
    <div class="viewport">
        <ul class="overview">           
            <li><img src="images/red-stripe.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/red-stripe-bw.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/red-stripe-red.jpg" /></li>            
            <li><img src="images/red-stripe-dark.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/red-stripe.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/red-stripe-red.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/red-stripe-dark.jpg" /></li>           
        </ul>
    </div>
    <a class="buttons next" href="#"></a>
    </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#slider-code { 
    height: 125px; 
    overflow:hidden;
    margin: auto;    /* top, right, bottom, left */ 
}

#slider-code .viewport { 
/*  margin-left: auto;    -- With this enabled, the arrows don't work.
    margin-right: auto;  */
    margin: 0 auto;    /* top, right, bottom, left */   
    width: 540px; 
    height: 125px; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    position: relative;
    float: left;

}

#slider-code .viewport .overview img {
    border: 4px solid #f6f6f7;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px; 
}

#slider-code .buttons { 
    display: block; 
    margin: 0 auto; /* top, right, bottom, left  */
    float: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#slider-code .prev {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background: transparent url('../images/left-arrow.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px; /* top, right, bottom, left */   
    position: relative;
/*  top: 190.5px;   */
}

#slider-code .next { 
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background: transparent url('../images/right-arrow.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;  /* 30px 0 0 10px; */
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
}

#slider-code .disable { 
     /* for IE */
    filter:alpha(opacity=40);
    /* for everything else */  
    opacity:0.4;
}

#slider-code .overview { 
    list-style: none; 
    position: absolute; 
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    left: 0; 
    top: 0; 
}

#slider-code .overview li { 
    float: left; 
    margin: 0 8px auto; /* top, right, bottom, left */  
    padding: 1px; 
    height: 121px; 
    border: 0px solid #dcdcdc;
    width: 236px;
}

.view_name {
    font-family: "Helvetica", serif;
    color: #f9f4c0;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 11px;
    word-spacing: 0px;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    background: #1a1a1a;    
    padding: 1px 3px 1px 3px; /* top, right, bottom, left */        
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
}
```

Here is the JS:

```
//Go Global with our varibles
    var oImg, sliderCode, sliderViewPort, win_width;
    var oImg_height, oImg_width, oImg_ratio, tImg_width, tImg_height, sliderCode_w, sliderCode_h, ul_width;
    var rImg_width, rImg_height, view_new_w, view_new_h, li_w, rUl_width;

    function setUp(numImages) {
        oImg_height = oImg.height(); //size of original image height 
        oImg_width = oImg.width(); //size of original image width 
        oImg_ratio = oImg_height / oImg_width; //aspect ratio of original image 
        tImg_width = (win_width * 0.915) / num_of_images; // Target image width = (90% of the window) / 2 
        tImg_height = tImg_width * oImg_ratio; // Target image height, resized according to the original image ratio. 
        sliderCode_w = $('#slider-code').width();
        sliderCode_h = $('#slider-code').height();
        var ul_width = $('#slider-code .viewport ul').width();

        //  console.log("Original Image Height: ", oImg_height, " Original Image Width: ", oImg_width, " Original Image Aspect Ratio: ", oImg_ratio, " Slider Code Width: ", sliderCode_w, " Slider Code Height: ", sliderCode_h, " Window Width: ", win_width, " UL Width: ", ul_width, " Target Image Width: ", tImg_width, " Target Image Height: ", tImg_height); 

        sliderCode = $('#slider-code .viewport .overview img:lt(26)').css({ 'width': tImg_width, 'height': tImg_height });   //resizes the images

        rImg_width = sliderCode.width(); // size of resized image width  
        rImg_height = sliderCode.height(); // size of resized image width 

        $('#slider-code .next').css({ 'top': rImg_height / 2 }); //This needs to be resolved for various size windows 
        $('#slider-code .prev').css({ 'top': rImg_height / 2 });
        $('#slider-code').css({ 'width': '100%', 'height': rImg_height + 10 }); //to accomodate borders, extra padding was added to heights. To make it truly dynamic, a variable (as a percentage) of the width of the window, could be used to be added to the height 
        $('#slider-code .viewport').css({ 'width': win_width * 0.94, 'height': rImg_height + 10 });
        $('#slider-code .overview li').css({ 'width': rImg_width + 5 });
        view_new_w = sliderViewPort.width();
        view_new_h = sliderViewPort.height();
        li_w = $('#slider-code .overview li').width();
        rUl_width = $('#slider-code .viewport ul').width();

        //  console.log("Viewport New Width: ", view_new_w, view_new_h, " List Item Width: ", li_w, " Resized Image Width: ", rImg_width, " Resized Image Height: ", rImg_height, " Resized UL Width: ", rUl_width); 

        $('#slider-code').tinycarousel({ controls: true, animation: true, display: 1 });

    }

$(window).load(function() {

 //Cache Some Common Elements
        oImg = $('#slider-code .viewport .overview img:eq(1)');
        sliderViewPort = $('#slider-code .viewport');

        // --------------------------- Begin Comparison Code --------------------------------------------------------        
        win_width = $(window).width();
        num_of_images = 2; //The number of images expected in view (2 for 2-up, 3 for 3-up, etc.) The default value is 2. 

        $("#viewbar img").click(function(e) {
            num_of_images = parseInt($(this).attr("data-id"), 10); // This accepts the integer associated with the navbar.           
            $('#viewname').text(num_of_images + '-up');

            setUp(num_of_images);

            e.preventDefault();
        });

        //Default set up
        setUp(num_of_images);

        // --------------- End Comparison Code -------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

})
```

Answer (score 2):

On a first look, it seems, that your viewport div's width isn't enought to show the border.

As an ugly hack, change the following line in your javascript:

```
sliderCode = $('#slider-code .viewport .overview img:lt(26)').css({ 'width': tImg_width, 'height': tImg_height });   //resizes the images
```

to

```
sliderCode = $('#slider-code .viewport .overview img:lt(26)').css({ 'width': tImg_width + 6, 'height': tImg_height });   //resizes the images
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: This doesn't quite do it. When I do this, it destroys the border on the 2 version view. Any thoughts on another way? I am tweaking it, to see if I can find what you were trying to do, but if you have a suggestion, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your `<li>`'s are `664px` wide, and your images are around `659px` wide. You have a `4px` border around the images, so you actually need a total width of `659 + 4 + 4 = 667`, which makes the `<li>`'s `3px` narrow, which is why the right side of the border is getting cut off.